# Unable to read document as soon as it is inserted

Tags: marklogic

I am trying to read document just after inserting it. I think insertion of document is in progress when I am trying to read it. Please let me know how can I achieve result using below snippet. Executing below code, give me error 'Cannot read property 'xpath' of null' .

```
declareUpdate();
xdmp.documentInsert("abc.xml",cts.doc("xyz.xml"));
return cts.doc("abc.xml").xpath("/root");
```

Answer (score 5):

OK. Here is a working example (assuming that xyz.xml is already in the database). But please see below the example.

```
declareUpdate();

xdmp.invokeFunction(function(){
    xdmp.documentInsert("abc.xml",cts.doc("xyz.xml"));
  },
  {
    transactionMode:"update-auto-commit",
    isolation:"different-transaction"
  }                   
);


cts.doc("abc.xml").xpath("/root");
```

This is certainly one of those times that simply copying and pasting the code above without understanding what is behind it is not a great idea. Not taking the time to understand transactions in MarkLogic will just leave you depressed and in a world of hurt. With that out of the way, some goodies are below:

Further Reading:

- [Understanding Transactions](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/transactions)
- [Visibility of Updates](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/transactions#id_85012)
- [Transaction Mode](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/transactions#id_25046)
- [Isolation option](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/transactions#id_24388)
- [Preventing Deadlocks](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/transactions#id_85082)

**Example Explained:**
The reason we need to place the document-insert into the invoke function is because we need to run it in a separate transaction. That is related to MarkLogic's Multi Version Concurrency Control (MVCC). Basically, the document did not exist at the time our scrip started to process. By using the combination of update and different transaction, we allow that transaction's committed document to be available to the calling code.

*But be careful* of when and how you decide to use this. As an example, If we read xyz.xml in the current transaction, and then tried to update the document in an invoked function, we get a deadlock - the first transaction waiting on the second and the second waiting on the first.

Example world of pain:

```
declareUpdate();

let doc  = cts.doc("xyz.xml");

xdmp.invokeFunction(function(){
   xdmp.nodeInsertChild(cts.doc("xyz.xml").xpath("/root"),
   fn.head(xdmp.unquote('<a>b</a>')).root);
},
  {
    transactionMode:"update-auto-commit",
    isolation:"different-transaction"
  }                   
);

cts.doc("xyz.xml");
```

The above looks innocent. It looks logical - update the doc in the other transaction and then read it. Nope... The first read causes the chicken/egg situation. This transaction will never finish.  You can add the option    `preventDeadlocks: true`. This will at least throw n error rather than hang. Moral of the story -understand transactions early on and understand why example 1 works and the similar example 2 does not.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is related to transaction boundaries. All of the updates within a transaction commit - and become live in the database - at the end of the transaction. In order to see the result of updates in one transaction, you must read from the database in a separate transaction that begins after the previous transaction has completed.

Comment: would it make sense to show an example of how to do the read in a different transaction?  I'd add it but I have no time right now.

Comment: @SamMefford Yes, but I am not ML-JS fluent!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend avoiding invoke and such unless you have no other option. Have you considered simply trusting that the insert will work, and you return the contents of 'xyz.xml'?

```
let doc = doc("xyz.xml");

xdmp.documentInsert("abc.xml", doc);

doc.xpath("/root");
```

HTH!